# There is an error while installing "npm i angularfire2"

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with angular project. I want to take `AngularFireStorage` by an import of this sort of `import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';`
For this I tried for it by this command `npm i angularfire2` But there was an error. I saw an article in a tutorial that describe as this. `"AngularFire has moved, we're now @angular/fire"` What is the meaning of this? Is it intent that `npm i angularfire2` is not working or something? However How I use `import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';` for attain `AngularFireStorage` to my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

angularfire2 is moved to @angular/fire that means they have changed the repo name.

use `npm install firebase @angular/fire --save` to install angularfire2 package.

and import like `import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';`

while importing just replace angularfire2 to @angular/fire

for more information - [Link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

Answer (score 1):

used this command:
`npm install firebase angularfire2 --save`
and import angular.module `import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';`

Comment: the angularfire2 package is deprecated see - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularfire2

Comment: then please add AngularFire has moved,  now `@angular/fire`